# Evaluate $\oint \exp\Big(\frac{A}{x-1}\Big) \cdot \exp\Big(\frac{B}{x-2}\Big) dx$ - Integral with two essential singularities?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, residue-calculus, singularity

I would like to solve that integral and I think the easiest (only reasonable???) solution is to find the residues. The contour is large enough to contain both singularities. So to recap, I would like to find the residues at the two essential singularities of the following function

$$f(x)=\exp\Big(\frac{A}{x-1}\Big) \cdot \exp\Big(\frac{B}{x-2}\Big)$$

Since the situation is symmetric the solution for one residue should suffice for now, so let us focus on the first singularity $x=1$. One Ansatz I have in mind is the following:

$$ f(x)=\Big(1+\frac{A}{x-1} + \frac{A^2}{2! (x-1)^2} + ...\Big)\cdot \exp\Big(\frac{B}{x-2}\Big) \\
=\Big(1+\frac{A}{x-1} + \frac{A^2}{2! (x-1)^2} + ...\Big)\cdot \Big(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{[d^n/dx^n\exp(B/(x-2))]_{x=1}}{n!} \cdot (x-1)^n\Big) \\
\rightarrow \mathrm{res}_{x=1} f(x) =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{[d^n/dx^n\exp(B/(x-2))]_{x=1} \cdot A^{n+1}}{n! (n+1)!} $$

so the first term is expanded just following the definition of the exponential function, and the second term is Taylor-expanded around $1$ to have factors of $(x-1)$ in order to cancel the respective factors in the first factor. Then all the terms giving a $\frac{1}{x-1}$ are added, which result in the final infinite sum.

Is this result correct? I think not, but I cannot find an error in the above construction. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Haven't had a chance to look at this thoroughly, would like to later though. Does it help you to write $exp(\frac{A}{z-1})\exp(\frac{B}{z-2}) = \exp\left( \frac{A(z-2) + B(z-1)}{(z-1)(z-2)}\right)$?

Comment: I dont't know. But why would that help? Dont you have to isolate one singularity at a time? Here you have them as a product in the denominator.

Comment: The simpler way to evaluate the integral is to consider the residue at $\infty$.

Comment: Could you maybe elaborate how that works for this problem? I am not familiar with the residue at $\infty$, and why it would help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\gamma$ is a contour winding once around both singularities, then by Cauchy's integral theorem we have

$$\int_{\gamma} f(z)\,dz = \int_{\lvert z\rvert = R} f(z)\,dz$$

for every $R > 2$. Choosing $R$ large, the expansion

\begin{align}
f(z) &= \Biggl(1 + \frac{A}{z-1} + O\biggl(\frac{1}{(z-1)^2}\biggr)\Biggr)\Biggl(1 + \frac{B}{z-2} + O\biggl(\frac{1}{(z-2)^2}\biggr)\Biggr) \\
&= 1 + \frac{A}{z-1} + \frac{B}{(z-2)} + O(z^{-2}) \\
&= 1 + \frac{A}{z} + \frac{B}{z} + O(z^{-2})
\end{align}

and the standard estimate (ML inequality) together show

$$\int_{\gamma} f(z)\,dz = 2\pi i(A + B) + O(R^{-1}),$$

so, since the left hand side is independent of $R$,

$$\int_{\gamma} f(z)\,dz = 2\pi i(A+B)$$

follows.

Comment: Thanks that is definately the right answer (which I got by other means). I wonder is my above construction wrong? I guess it is necessary to use that R > 2, so that it encompasses 0 and 2? The thing I do not quite understand is how you get from $\frac{A}{z-1}$ to $\frac{A}{z}$, i.e. you just neglect the  fact that it was $x-1$?

Comment: We have $\frac{A}{z-1} - \frac{A}{z} = \frac{A}{z(z-1)}$, and for $\lvert z\rvert \geqslant 2$, we can estimate the right hand side by $\frac{2\lvert A\rvert}{\lvert z\rvert^2}$ (since $\lvert z-1\rvert \geqslant \frac{1}{2}\lvert z\rvert$). Similar for $\frac{B}{z-2} - \frac{B}{z}$ (when $\lvert z\rvert \geqslant 4$). Your ansatz is correct. But it's not entirely trivial to obtain the result from that, there are a number of opportunities to make mistakes.

Comment: But does that then mean that: $A+B=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{[d^n/dx^n\exp(B/(x-2))]_{x=1} \cdot A^{n+1}}{n! (n+1)!} + \frac{[d^n/dx^n\exp(A/(x-1))]_{x=2} \cdot B^{n+1}}{n! (n+1)!} $ ?Btw. is there a third way to solve that integral?

Comment: Yes, it does mean that. There's enough symmetry that evaluating the series is manageable, but it's still better to avoid that. Another way to evaluate it (which, however, is in some sense equivalent to letting $R\to +\infty$) is to make a substitution $w = 1/z$. That leads to $\int_{\tilde{\gamma}} \frac{h(w)}{w^2}\,dw$, where $h(w) = f(1/w)$, and by the integral formula you need to determine $h'(0)$ (which isn't too bad). Both of these ways amount to evaluating $$\int_{\gamma} f(z)\,dz = -2\pi i \operatorname{Res}(f;\infty)\,.$$

Comment: Could you elaborate how you would evaluate these series? I cannot see the equality just by staring at it ;)

Comment: Staring doesn't help much ;) By induction, show that there are polynomials $P_n$ of two variables, so that the $n^{\text{th}}$ derivative of $g(z) = \exp\frac{c}{z}$ has the form $g(z)\cdot P_n(c,z^{-1})$ (for $z\neq 0$). Then $$\biggl(\frac{d}{dx}\biggr)^n\biggr\rvert_{x = 1} \exp(B/(x-2)) = e^{-B}P_n(B,(-1))\quad\text{and}\quad \biggl(\frac{d}{dx}\biggr)^n\biggr\rvert_{x = 2} \exp(A/(x-1)) = e^{A}P_n(A,1)\,.$$ Using a recursion formula for the $P_n$ - and a nontrivial amount of work - one can obtain the result. But I'd rather not.

Comment: Ah ok. I was thinking along the lines of Faà di Bruno's formula for the nth derivative, which can be rewritten for the exponential in terms of complete exponential Bell polynomials. But then I got stuck .. also I dont know if that would have led anywhere.

Comment: I don't know. If one has the right idea along the way, that would lead to the result, but the right idea is probably non-obvious.