# Evaluate $\oint z^2 \cdot \exp\Big(\frac{A}{z-1}\Big) \cdot \exp\Big(\frac{B}{z-2}\Big) dz$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, residue-calculus, singularity

This is basically a follow-up question to "[Evaluate $\oint \exp\Big(\frac{A}{x-1}\Big) \cdot \exp\Big(\frac{B}{x-2}\Big) dx$ - Integral with two essential singularities?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2571146/evaluate-oint-exp-big-fracax-1-big-cdot-exp-big-fracbx-2-big-dx)", where an additional $x^2$ (or $z^2$) term is in front of the exponential factors. How would you go about this one? I am not sure the same solution as to the other problem applies, as the simplifications with the extra $z^2$ term might not be possible in a similar way. So what is the solution to 
$$ \oint z^2 \cdot \exp\Big(\frac{A}{z-1}\Big) \cdot \exp\Big(\frac{B}{z-2}\Big) dz$$ ? Again the contour can be as large as required. Any help or insight greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not use **exactly** the same approach? If $$\exp\left(\frac{A}{z-1}+\frac{B}{z-2}\right)=1+\frac az+\frac b{z^2}+\frac c{z^3}+o\left(\frac1{z^3}\right)$$ then the integral is $$2i\pi c$$ hence all you have to do is to compute the expansion $$\frac{A}{z-1}+\frac{B}{z-2}=\frac \alpha z+\frac \beta{z^2}+\frac \gamma{z^3}+o\left(\frac1{z^3}\right)$$ and to deduce $c$ from it.

Comment: Sorry but this is not the same approach as before as I understand it. Before we used the residue at infinity, and did some simplifications along the way. Do you use this here aswell? Also it is not clear to me how you would deduce c from the second expansion - maybe you could elaborate more.

Comment: @Did: Your advice is formally OK but practically confusing.  There is no singularity at $z=0$ so why would one expand the integrand in a Laurent series about that point?  The singularities are at $z=1$ and $z=2$, so, for example, at $z=1$, expand the integrand as follows:

$$(\zeta+1)^2 \left [1+\frac{A}{\zeta}+\frac{A^2}{2! \zeta^2} +\frac{A^3}{3! \zeta^3} + \cdots \right ] \exp{\left (\frac{B}{\zeta-1} \right )} $$

where $\zeta=z-1$.

Comment: (and yes, that exponential on the right would also need to be expanded in a Laurent series...)

Comment: @RonGordon Sorry but I do not see the confusion. For every $|z|>2$, the series expansion of the rational fraction and of its exponential both converge absolutely, so where is the problem?

Comment: @ThorstenGlu "this is not the same approach as before" How so? The next sentences in your comment do not explain why the approach in the answer you received there (which I parrot in my comment) would not work. The only additional ingredients might be that $$\oint z^2dz=\oint zdz=0$$ while the former case only uses, as far as nonnegative powers of $z$ are concerned, that $$\oint dz=0$$ Is this what is blocking you?

Comment: @Did: After thinking on this a bit I think you have a point.  I was just saying I found it confusing, not wrong.  But on further reflection, your way may be faster.

Comment: @Did Hm maybe it is clear for the usual math expert, but not for me ^^ indeed the expansion around 0 was a little confusing, I am still thinking in terms of expanding around the poles given. The last integrals over nonnegatie powers of z are clear, what is not so clear to me is how to get from the $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ to c .. probably it should be obvious but I am not seeing it at the moment.

Comment: Note that $$e^t=1+t+\frac12t^2+\frac16t^3+o(t^3)$$ when $t\to0$ hence, if $$u(z)=\frac \alpha z+\frac \beta{z^2}+\frac \gamma{z^3}+o\left(\frac1{z^3}\right)$$ when $z\to\infty$ then $$e^{u(z)}=1+u(z)+\frac12u(z)^2+\frac16u(z)^3+o\left(\frac1{z^3}\right)$$ hence $$e^{u(z)}=1+\frac \alpha z+\frac \beta{z^2}+\frac \gamma{z^3}+\frac12\left(\frac \alpha z+\frac \beta{z^2}\right)^2+\frac16\left(\frac \alpha z\right)^3+o\left(\frac1{z^3}\right)$$ from which the value of $(a,b,c)$  should be clear.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah actually I was coming to the same conclusion  after thinking about it a little bit.. question closed, learned something.